# HTML code to stay at the current page when switching language

Tags: php, html

I'm writing this website which has a navigation bar on top of the window on which there's a toggle list that you can choose language you use to view this website.

I managed to wrote the code for the language switching button and here's the code:

```html
<li class="dropdown ' . (in_array($currentFile,$servicesArr)?'active':'') . '">
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
    <img src="assets/images/flags/cn.png" width="16" height="11" alt="CN 語言" /> [CN] 简体中文<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="index.php">
          <img src="assets/images/flags/hk.png" width="16" height="11" alt="CN 語言" /> [HK] 繁體中文</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">
         <img src="assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="EN Language" /> [US] English</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

So, my question is: according to my code, everytime I change a language, the link will take to the index of that language, but what if I'm not at the index page of my current language? Say, if I'm viewing index-en/job.php in English, now I want to switch to Chinese, instead of going to index-cn after click on the toggle button, I want to switch to index-cn/job.php. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the `php` tag, so I'm guessing this is a PHP file.  You can use PHP to dynamically populate the `href` attribute with the corresponding pages in the other languages.

1. Get the current URL and language
2. Compute what the matching URLs would be for the other languages.
3. Insert matching URLs in the `href` attributes of your links.

Code:

```
<?php
//URL path. eg: index-en/job.php
$path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');

//language from URL. eg: index-en
$lang = explode('/',$path)[0];

//Paths in other languages: eg: 'cn' => 'index-cn/job.php'
$langs = [
    'en'=>preg_replace("/$lang/",'index-en',$path,1),
    'cn'=>preg_replace("/$lang/",'index-cn',$path,1),
    ...
];
?>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="<?= $langs['cn']?>">
            <img src="assets/images/flags/hk.png" width="16" 
                      height="11" alt="CN 語言" /> [HK] 繁體中文</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="<?= $langs['en']?>">
            <img src="assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" 
                      height="11" alt="EN Language" /> [US] English</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```